# Дополнительные поля в Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, cms

Задача состоит в том, чтобы установить дополнительные поля вручную.

```
<?php 
// GET CUSTOM FIELDS
$myCustomFields = array();
foreach($this->item->jcfields as $field) {
    $myCustomFields[$field->name] = $field->value;
} 
// RECOVER CUSTOM FILED NAME
if (isset($myCustomFields['field-1']) and !empty($myCustomFields['field-1'])) : ?>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="field__name">Название поля:</div>
        <div class="field__value"><?php echo $myCustomFields['field-1']; ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

с выводом дополнительных полей непосредственно в шаблоне article.php проблем не возникает.
но мне нужно вывести их в шаблон категории блога. При попытке вывести поле возникает ошибка

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\OpenServer\domains\center-skidok.loc\templates\centerskidok\html\com_tags\tag\default_items.php on line 65